# A wifi network does not connect while others do

Tags: wireless

I have a college Wi-Fi network. While I am on Windows it connects without any problem and when I switch to Ubuntu then it refuses to even connect and reports `Activation of network connection failed`. What can be done to solve the problem?

In college there are also other Wi-Fi networks and they connect without any problem and this problem is only with one network.

syslog: https://pastebin.com/QHxAg5sg

Comment: Start by consulting the `syslog`/`journalctl`

Comment: I have done that but still not able to understand the reason. (also added the syslog in the post)